# Highlight multiple div class with link

Tags: class, html, onclick, hyperlink, nav

**Hi everyone** - After countless searching, i'm still not exactly sure what the terminology is that i'm looking for (*It seems so simple*). So it's been hard to try and find some progress... Sorry i have no code to show at this point, still trying to figure out the best direction for the solution.

An example of what i'm after can be seen at **www.anishkapoor.com** - Basically i'm trying to create a very similar navigation where content is catagorised by colour, after clicking on a particular nav link it highlights (changes colour) of all content with the same class ID. Obviously when a new nav link is selected the current highlighted content will switch to the new class ID. I'm also trying to write this code so it can be easily applied to a CMS. Thank you for your time and i hope i've made some sense.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Have you tried anything ? Most people won't do your work for you ( unless you want to pay :) ). Post your code and you'll get pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, but it's a pretty basic attempt. **[jsfiddle.net/bH6pg/1](http://jsfiddle.net/bH6pg/1)**
I'm going to apply this to a wordpress so if someone has a better solution for CMS, please inform :-)

```
 $(".oranges").click(function () {
  $(".orange").addClass("orange_highlight");
  $('.apple').removeClass("apple_highlight");
  $('.banana').removeClass("banana_highlight");
});
```